# crontab unable to find the running process

Tags: shell, cron

crontab  looks as below:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

* * * * *  /home/zaks/influx_rabbitmq_restorer.sh > /home/zaks/crontab.txt 2>&1
```

`influx_rabbitmq_restorer.sh`:

```
ps -aux | grep -v grep | grep rabbitmq_restorer
RESULT=$?
echo $RESULT
if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "running"
else
   echo "not running"
   (nohup python -u  /home/zaks/rabbitmq_restorer.py  )
fi
```

1. When I manually run the script `/home/zaks/influx_rabbitmq_restorer.sh`the result is 1 ("not running").
2. But cronjob log at `/home/zaks/crontab.txt` shows:

   ```
   zaks 11612  0.0  0.0  12504  2936 ?        Ss   03:15   0:00 /bin/bash -c /home/zaks/influx_rabbitmq_restorer.sh > /home/zaks/crontab.txt 2>&1
   zaks 11613  0.0  0.0  12516  2388 ?        S    03:15   0:00 /bin/bash -c /home/zaks/influx_rabbitmq_restorer.sh > /home/zaks/crontab.txt 2>&1
   0
   running
   ```

cronjob is unable to detect `rabbitmq_restorer` process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit first line of the script to be like:

```
ps -aux | grep -v grep | grep -v influx_rabbitmq_restorer.sh| grep rabbitmq_restorer
```